# How to combine two DataFrame Structures in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm looking for a combination of two DataFrame structures in Python using a (shared) index value column.

Data snippet:

```
d1 = {'col1': ['entry1', 'entry2', 'entry3'], 'col2': [1, 2,3]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

d2= {'col1': ['entry2', 'entry3', 'entry1'], 'priority': [4, 2 , 7]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

The result should be something like

```
col1     col2    priority  
----     ----    ----
entry1   1       7
entry2   2       4
entry3   3       2
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a [few options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html):

You can use `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('col1'), df2.set_index('col1')], axis=1)
```

This gives you

```
       col2  priority
entry1     1         7
entry2     2         4
entry3     3         2
```

So `col1` becomes your index.

If it should be a column, you can use `merge`

```
df1.merge(df2)
```

which gives

```
     col1  col2  priority
0  entry1     1         7
1  entry2     2         4
2  entry3     3         2
```

or

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col1')
```

yielding

```
     col1  col2  priority
0  entry1     1         7
1  entry2     2         4
2  entry3     3         2
```

Another option is then also `join`

```
df1.set_index('col1').join(df2.set_index('col1'))
```

which gives

```
        col2  priority
col1                  
entry1     1         7
entry2     2         4
entry3     3         2
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much, that was within 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to have - thanks :-)

Comment: @Stevie: Good to know :)

Answer (score -1):

Simple as

```
frames = [df1.set_index('col1'), df2.set_index('col1'), axis = 1]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Comment: `frames = [df1set_index('col1'), df2set_index('col1'), axis = 1]` is syntax error.